# "NO IDENT RESPONSE" error when connecting to an IRC server

Tags: python, sockets, irc

Usually I would attempt something like this with the twisted library, but that isn't available for python 3 - so I attempted it using the sockets library. The code does establish a connection, but the server quickly responds with "no ident response". I don't have much network programming experience, so I would appreciate it if someone could point out the error I'm making here. I'm also quite aware that there are functions/other code that aren't used, or that Ive used inconsistently. I just thought I would paste the entirety of my code here in case its relevant.

```
import socket

server = "irc.freenode.net"
channel = "put channel here"
nickname = "put nickname here"


def encode(text):
    return text.encode("ascii")


def ping():
    irc_socket.send(encode("PONG :pingis\n"))


def send_message(chan, msg):
    irc_socket.send(encode("PRIVMSG " + chan + " :" + msg + "\n"))


def join_channel(chan):
    irc_socket.send(encode("JOIN " + chan + "\n"))

def login(username='user', realname='Pythonist', hostname='Helena', servername='Server'):
    irc_socket.send(encode("USER %s %s %s %s" % (username, hostname, servername, realname)))
    irc_socket.send(encode("NICK " + nickname))


irc_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
irc_socket.connect((server, 6667))
login()
join_channel(channel)

while True:
    buffer = irc_socket.recv(1024)
    msg = str.split(str(buffer))
    if msg[0] == "PING":
        irc_socket.send("PONG %s" % msg[1])
    print(msg)
```

The code was originally from: http://wiki.shellium.org/w/Writing_an_IRC_bot_in_Python and Ive made minor changes.

Comment: “No ident response” isn’t really an error. You’ll usually see it even if you use a desktop client.

Comment: You will have head hurts with copy-paste :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Teensy tiny little problem that’s causing all the trouble: you’re missing newlines in `login`. `"USER %s %s %s %s"` should be `"USER %s %s %s %s\n"` and `"NICK " + nickname` should be `"NICK " + nickname + "\n"`. The server looks up your ident and doesn’t find it, and the next step after that is for you to register, but you never send it a complete line, so it keeps waiting… and waiting…

Answer (score 4):

[Ident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ident_protocol) is UNIX service which nobody has been using for twenty years or so.

It was used to identify the remote user when doing terminal server to remote server connections in terminal applications. Ident is no way safe for modern internet, so nobody is using it anymore.

So you have hit the ghost of the past. Also, as mentioned in the above answer, if you send correct `NICK` command the IRC server is happy with your client.